# Having trouble verifying op-amp on circuit board

Tags: operational-amplifier, kirchhoffs-laws, breadboard, testing

I'm having trouble verifying that I understand how op-amps work (because I clearly don't!). I've hooked up the following circuit on my breadboard:

[image]

The voltage sources are two 9 V batteries, the resistors are \$R_1=660\ \Omega\$ and \$R_2=970\ \Omega\$. My understanding of how to do Kirchoff's / Ohm's laws here are:

- Since no current can flow into the op-amp, the current through \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ is the same, call it \$I\$.
- The voltage at the negative (inverting input) is \$-V_-=I\cdot R_1\$. That's the same voltage at the positive \$V_+\$(non-inverting input), again by the properties of op-amps.
- Across the second resistor we have \$I\cdot R_2=V_- - V_{out}\$. Since \$V_+-V_-\$, that's:

$$
V_{out}=V_+-I\cdot R_2=V_+-(-\frac{V_{+}}{R_1})R_2=V_+(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1})
$$

That's good, because casual Googling gets me the same answer. But, when I hook this circuit up, I get *less* than the original voltage (like 7.4 V, reading the low end of a battery to \$V_{out}\$). Nothing changes when I switch the second resistor to something else much larger (\$50\ \Omega\$), and actually, when \$V_1=0\$ (battery off), I get the exact same result for the output - like 7.4 V.

So there are a number of things here that are new to me, but I've failed in my debugging things I suspect I don't understand. My actual breadboard is here, although I doubt it's clear enough to figure out what's going on. (You can see the voltmeter reading from the negative rail to the output on pin 4 (yellow wire).

[image]

The op-amp is connected so that the pins 1-5 match the labeling on the board. I am using a [TDA2050](https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/TDA2050-Datasheet.pdf) op-amp.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong, either theoretically or when constructing the board?

Comment: OP amps generally need headroom, and can't output voltages as high as the power supply.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Oh no way ...so you're saying if I applied only like, 5V to the non-inverting input, the equation I wrote would actually work? So long as 5V didn't get boosted to over 9 V (or maybe the max is 7.4 V ?)

Comment: Well, you're asking for a gain more than 2, so 5 volts input is still too high, but yeah, 1V would work

Comment: And removing the battery isn't the same as grounding the input, which would be V=0. Also, the op amp needs headroom ag both ends, so the output can't go all the way to zero, either.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Ok, I grabbed a 1.5 V, calculated 2.5 on the output, and got a reading of 2.8 V. I guess I'll count that as "fixed". I admit, I don't understand your comment about grounding vs being the low side of the battery (I guess that's some kind of "floating" ground, but I don't see it's relevance here.) If you want to add that as an answer (with maybe a link to details?) I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: A TDA2050 is most definitely *not* an "opamp". It's an audio power amplifier which *might* behave a bit like an opamp for some use-cases, but trying to use it as an opamp in general is going to lead to disappointment. If you want to learn about opamp, you need to get an actual opamp - something like an LM358 or LM324.

Comment: @brhans ok now you're just blowing my mind. The circuit element looks like an Op Amp, so that's what I've been calling it! I'm trying to understand and fix a guitar amplifier, which uses these TDA 2050s. Maybe I should build the test circuit in the documentation....?

Comment: While the TDA2050 is technically an audio power amplifier, it does in fact behave just like an opamp (and is also constructed like one internally). You could also call it a high-power opamp, and it can be treated as such when doing circuit analysis. The biggest difference between a TDA2050 and something like a LM358 is the fact that the TDA2050 can drive a *lot* of current. (And that its bandwidth is lower.) So, in short, the TDA2050 is an "actual opamp" too.

Comment: You need a capacitor before R1. TDA2050 used as AC amplifier...

Comment: @Antonio51 I think what you're getting at is we can use a capacitor to "block DC signals", right? That might be applicable if I was testing this thing with an oscilloscope, but right now I'm just using a multimeter. I think more complex testing is beyond me at this moment...

Comment: Right because TDA2050 is a "power" amplifier. But don't give up. Just use a "classic" op-amp (resistors between 1k and 10k for the beginning) with a bipolar supply. You have just to use a "center" point for reference which is the ground. And your schematic is ok. No need for a scope.